# Subscript out of bound while running the model in r using nimble package

Tags: r, nimble

I am running the following code in R

```
nimbleNBModel <- nimbleModel(code = nbModel, name = 'nimbleNBModel', 
                             constants = Consts, data = nimbleData, inits = inits)
```

I am getting an error of

> defining model...
>   Error in decl$symbolicParentNodesReplaced[[which(vars[idx] == decl$rhsVars)]] : 
>     subscript out of bounds

Can anybody suggest what is going wrong....

Comment: It looks like there is some problem with model dimensions or dynamic indexing. This depends on the model code you have, so I am not able to say much more without seeing that.
Any, I would recommend you to use the [nimble-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nimble-users) Google group, for NIMBLE related questions. It is a pretty active channel and always under the eyes of the developers.